# Написание приставки "сверх-" с прилагательными

Tags: орфография

В контексте: "До выдачи заданий в ПС необходимо решить вопрос о транспорте материалов, оборудования, грунта, строительного мусора, сверх учтенного в расценках". - слово "сверх учтенного" - пишется раздельно или слитно? И, если можно, объясните подробно, почему.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае пишется раздельно.
"Сверх" здесь действительно не приставка, а предлог.
"Учтенного", "учтенный" это , конечно, причастие, хотя  в принципе может быть и прилагательным и даже субстаниватом (существительным). 
Фразу "образует падежную форму существительного" я не совсем понимаю, но по другой причине, по сути-то всё правльно сказано, мне только термин не понравился.
Предлог "сверх" **управляет** падежом следующего за ним существительного, в т.ч. - умалчиваемого ("товара"). А причастие или прилагатенльное, в свою очередь **согласуется** с этим существительным - "учтённого [товара]". Вроде я здесь термины не переврал (а если даже и переврал, то смысл понятен). А вот насчет "образует" я что-то не соображу, что имеется в виду.

В принципе допускаю и существование понятия "сверхучтённый" (= излишне, ошибочно учтённый), но в данном контексте он никак не просматривается. Поэтому написание раздльно.

Answer (score 0):

Приставки. конечно, пишутся слитно. Только приставка ли это? Сверх учтенного - т.е. помимо учтенного, кроме учтенного - это производный предлог,образует падежную форму существительного (учтенного), следовательно, пишем отдельно.

Comment: а разве слово "учтенного" это существительное? разве это не причастие?